# pandas map to dictionary of array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

i have a df of country codes:

```
  cntr
0 CN
1 CH
```

and I want to map the full name and region I have from a dictionary

```
cntrmap = {"CN":["China","Asia"],"CH":["Switzerland","Europe"]}
```

I was hoping in something like this, but doesn't work..

```
df['name'] = df['cntr'].map(cntrmap)[0]
df['region'] = df['cntr'].map(cntrmap)[1]
```

do you guys have any suggestion?
thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper DataFrame by [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original DataFrame by default left join:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cntr':['CN','CH']})

cntrmap = {"CN":["China","Asia"],"CH":["Switzerland","Europe"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cntrmap, orient='index', columns=['name','region'])

df = df.join(df1, on='cntr')
print (df)
  cntr         name  region
0   CN        China    Asia
1   CH  Switzerland  Europe
```

Your solution works if create 2 dictionaries for `map`:

```
map1 = {k:v[0] for k, v in cntrmap.items()}
map2 = {k:v[1] for k, v in cntrmap.items()}

df['name'] = df['cntr'].map(map1)
df['region'] = df['cntr'].map(map2)
```

Comment: yes I see.. thank you jezrael! not sure why you cannot map on the internal array, it feels intuitive to me. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to achieve the same with `map`:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['cntr'].map(m).tolist(), columns=['name', 'region']))
```

Output:

```
  cntr         name  region
0   CN        China    Asia
1   CH  Switzerland  Europe
```

Comment: Dont use `apply(pd.Series)` it is slow. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns/35491399#35491399)